# Moving view when keyboard shows for secureTextEntry

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uitextfield

I'm trying to move my self.view up, when the keyboard appears.

I used the normal:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
```

in my `viewDidLoad()`, like I usually do. With these 2 functions.

```
func keyboardWillShow(sender: NSNotification) {
    self.view.frame.origin.y -= 160
}
func keyboardWillHide(sender: NSNotification) {
    self.view.frame.origin.y += 160
}
```

However this particular view. has different keyboard types for it's `UITextFields`.

Specifically, these textfields are:

```
firstName - normal keyboard
lastName - normal keyboard
email - email keyboard
password - secureTextEntry
```

My usual functions seems to work fine for all of them except the password. Unfortunately, when I click "next/return" on my email `UITextField`. It moves my view up another 160 points.

it obviously thinks I'm adding another keyboard, without removing one.

My first thought was to simply, change the value when that specific `UITextField` is called. But the view acts as it's supposed to when I just click the password `UITextField`.

It only messes up when I'm currently in one of the other views, then clicking next, or tapping the password `UITextFIeld`, so I can't just specify how much the view moves, in `textFieldShouldReturn` either.

How do I move the view up properly, taking the secureTextEntry problem into account?

As suggested by Joko Sarmiento I tried this as well:

```
var originalFrame: CGRect!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    originalFrame = self.view.frame
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    self.view.frame = originalFrame
    return false
}
```

I also added `self.view.frame = originalFrame` to my touchesBegan event, since as mentioned before, it's not only on return.

But the above attempt didn't work, here's a screenshot of the password field after having clicked next from the email field. And it stays that way after dismissing the textfield as well.

[image]

I also tried moving it up with `self.view.frame = originalframe.origin.y+160` instead. But still causes a problem with the password field.

The reason it messes up is due to my errorView, which changes height. Making it so the `originalFrame` is now incorrect.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced this a while back. It seems your `keyboardWillHide:` method isn't being called when the password field is made first responder.

You could reset your view's origin to its original value in `textFieldShouldReturn:`, not by adding `160px`, but having an `originalValue` variable that you set in `viewDidLoad`.

You can do something like:

```
var originalFrame: CGRect!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    originalFrame = self.view.frame
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    self.view.frame = originalFrame

    return false
}
```

**Edit 1:**

I just noticed that the above code will only work if you tap the return button. You should reset the view's frame whenever a text field resigns the first responder.

---

**Edit 2:**

This problem should be easily solved if you used a `UIScrollView` in your content view. Embed your form elements in `UIScrollView` and whenever the app fires `keyboardWillShow:` or `keyboardWillHide:`, you adjust the `contentInset` property of the `UIScrollView` based on keyboard height (which you can get from the notification's `userInfo`).

Anyway, since you solved the problem without having to use a `UIScrollView`, here's an explanation on why your approach didn't work and how you might have gotten it to work:

1. First, You were trying to subtract/add a fixed height of `160px` to the content view. You have to understand that the keyboard height differs on different devices. A good approach is to use the keyboard height that you get from `NSNotification` `userInfo`. This is easily retrieved via `notification.userInfo` in your `keyboardWillShow:` or `keyboardWillHide:`.
2. You were not resetting `self.view` to its original frame. This can cause the frame's Y origin to be modified multiple times without being reset, causing the subtracted pixels to double, etc. Since you're using `self.view.frame.origin.y -= 160`, if the `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` notification didn't fire when you switch to your password field, the frame's origin will not reset, and subtract an additional `160px`.
3. `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` may not have been firing all this time, whenever you switch your password text field. I still need to confirm this but it could be the reason why your `keyboardWillHide:` function isn't being called, thus subtracting an additional `160px` instead of adding `160px` then subtracting `160px`.

Comment: Tried it, but it still messes up. I'll edit my post with an updated screenshot

Comment: Is there a specific reason you can't use a UIScrollView? If you can, this will help a lot: http://creativecoefficient.net/swift/keyboard-management/

Comment: I redid the viewController with a scrollview. And added the exact code in the link. However, nothing moves when I tap a textfield and the keyboard shows up. (my scrollview is named the same).

Comment: After a while I finally managed to get a version working. To be honest I'm not sure why this works? But I havn't been able to break it, using this code:

`func keyboardWillShow(sender: NSNotification) {
        self.view.frame.origin.y = originalFrameY-100
    }
    func keyboardWillHide(sender: NSNotification) {
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 50, self.view.bounds.width, self.view.bounds.height)
    }`

where `originalFrameY` is `self.view.frame.origin.y` set in `viewDidLoad()`. I don't know if you can explain why this worked? or perhaps edit your answer, and I'll accept it.